# Stop extend and subscribe on observable for a different page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, publish-subscribe

I dont know how this works in retrospective when moving to a different page in a SPA.  I have a certain page where I would always like to be notified of an update, and subscribe to it.  However, this observable `hasUpdate` is used on other pages, kind of like a global variable.  Do the extend and subscribe go away on a page change, or can I do this myself?  If I can do this myself by changing it to null or something on a different page how would yo do that?  Also if I only want to remove one subscribe out of two, can you do that with an id of the subscribe or something?

```
app.viewModel.members.hasUpdate.extend({
    notify: 'always'
});

app.viewModel.members.hasUpdate.subscribe(function () {
    viewModel.modificationCheck.update();
});
```

Comment: Did you like the answer you chose as "accepted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription's `dispose` method is what you're looking for.  Knockout has no conception of "pages" or "navigation", so you'll have to handle this logic yourself.  The simplest case looks something like:

```
hasUpdateSubscription = app.viewModel.members.hasUpdate.subscribe(function () {
    viewModel.modificationCheck.update();
});

//When you change pages

hasUpdateSubscription.dispose();
```

Realistically, though you probably want some more structured way of doing this.  Personally, I'd suggest a KO ViewModel for each page.  Something like:

```
function PageOneViewModel() {
    hasUpdateSubscription = app.viewModel.members.hasUpdate.subscribe(function () {
        viewModel.modificationCheck.update();
    });

    this.dispose = function() {
        hasUpdateSubscription.dispose();
    }
}
```

Then pages can be handles with a `currentPage` observable on your root viewModel, so page changing logic would include something like:

```
var newPageVM = new PageTwoViewModel();  //create a view model for page 2
var oldPageVM = app.currentPage();
app.currentPage(newPageVM); //set page 2 as the current VM
oldPageVM.dispose();  //page VM dispose function should clean up subscriptions, etc.
```